# How can I pass 2 values to my ValueConverters Class?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have got this on my Xaml , I am passing value allocated to change gridcell colour. But I want to check also at same time Entered variable value so I can change according to that.How can I pass 2 values so I can have conditions on my iconverter class.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Allocated}" Header="Allocated" >
                     <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Allocated, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>     </DataGridTextColumn>
```

my Converter class:

object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture){

```
         string input = value.ToString(); 

         switch (input) 
         { 
             case "99":
                 return Brushes.Green;
             case "96":
                 return Brushes.Green;
             case "91":
              default:   
                 return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; 
         }

    }
```

> Blockquote

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx):

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                    <Binding Path="Allocated" />
                    <Binding Path="Entered" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

and ake your convet implement `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {...
```

Comment: Thank u...Its working I am new to wpf and wasnt aware of multibinding.